# jquery TypeError: state is undefined var options = state.options;

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, I was on a little earlier having an issue with a jQuery function about slide toggles. Got that running by itself on a page with nothing interrupting it. Then I added this code:

```
$(function () {
$('#toggle4').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').hide('1000');
    $('.toggle').text('toggle 4 clicked');
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

    return false;
});
});

 $(function () {
 $('#toggle3').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').hide('1000');
    $('.toggle').text('toggle 3 clicked');
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

    return false;
});
});
```

to my script.js file where my javascript is and the code won't run. There appears to be something in that code that is not allowing the toggle to run. When I run it on the page in HTML, I click it and all it does is return me to the top of the page instead of working correctly. My script.js file is here http://jsfiddle.net/9e4uM/1/ .

When I read the console, the error in the subject is what is present. If I take out the script.js file and just post the code on the HTML page, it works. But once I add it back it doesn't. I need the script.js file because of other scripts running on the page. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: What's your console say? -- JSFiddle says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined`

Comment: your fiddle requires jquery which is not added now

Comment: I have this in the HTML file "js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: It points to this in the console var options = state.options; in the file: startInterval: function () {
var state = $(this).data('state');
var options = state.options;
var initThis = this;
state.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
internal.nextUsePause.call(initThis);
}, options.pause);
}  .... this is in firefox browser

Comment: Try `$('#toggle4').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Yes it doesn't work because your jsfiddle does not include jquery. Also best not to add google analytics code...http://jsfiddle.net/9e4uM/2/

Comment: Yes, the code in that fiddle works, it just doesn't work with the rest of the javascript codes that I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div>
      <a href="#" id="toggle3">Slide Toggle3</a><br /><br />
      <a href="#" id="toggle4">Slide Toggle4</a><br /><br />
     <div class="toggle" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:200px;"></div>
 </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#toggle4').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').hide('1000');
    $('.toggle').text('toggle 4 clicked');
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

    return false;
});
});

$(function () {
$('#toggle3').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').hide('1000');
    $('.toggle').text('toggle 3 clicked');
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

    return false;
});
});
Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/indianchiran/fe75zct2/ and in your code cannot read property mozilla error will come for that error please go though this link http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=3972
```